# PHP-Laravel redirect to root(/) from /index.php

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

I'm working on a larvel project where everything is fine when I enter the url(domain) without `/index.php`. Suppose my url is `https://example.com`. When I go to this url, everything works perfectly. But if I add `/index.php` at the last like `https://example.com/index.php`, my resources(images, videos) are not loading because of path mismatch. So far I figure out I need to redirect that `https://example.com/index.php` to `https://example.com` by defining rules on `.htaccess` file.

So how can I write the rules correctly so that it redirects to `https://example.com` when I enter `https://example.com/index.php` ?

**Update:** In development my project is running on `http://localhost:3000/Example`. In this case I need to redirect this `http://localhost:3000/Example/index.php` to `http://localhost:3000/Example`.

Comment: [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23837933/12443754)

Answer (score 3):

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

turn on RewriteEngine and add above lines below RewriteEngine On

Comment: Your answer supposes to work. But in my case, it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`. I update my question.  Would you please see that?

Comment: isn't it redirecting from (http://localhost:3000/dashboard/index.php) to (http://localhost:3000/dashboard/)?