# how to remove index.php from the url in laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-routing, laravel-http-client

suppose my site open with the url `https://www.example.com` and it also opens with the `https://www.example.com/index.php` but i want it to open only with the `https://www.example.com` ONLY and not with `https://www.example.com/index.php`

just want to know how to remove index.php from my url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Remove “public/index.php” in the URL Generated Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel)

Answer (score -2):

You can create a route with `https://www.example.com/index.php` that will redirect to user to `https://www.example.com` whenever user try to access `https://www.example.com/index.php`.

Eg. In you web.php file you can add a route like this.

```
Route::get('https://www.example.com/index.php', function () { 
    return redirect('https://www.example.com');
});
```